# Как изменить bit-ность нескольких изображений в ffmpeg?

Tags: cmd, ffmpeg

У меня есть очень много иконок с bit-ностью цвета 4bit и 8bit. Мне их все надо преобразовать в 32bit цвет, так как при удалении ненужных размеров всех этих иконок (мне нужен размер 32*32) я получаю чёрный фон, в то время как его в оригинале не было. Таких иконок около 500, а вручную переделывать, это как минимум на весь день.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы  воспользовался универсальным средством обработки растровых изображений **ImageMagick**. А именно утилитой **convert**.

Вот пример команды Windows для массовой обработки всех вложенных иконок в требуемом каталоге  с перезаписью файлов.

```
for /r "c:\Folder with Icons" %i in (*.ico) do "c:\program\ImageMagick\convert.exe" "%~i" -resize x32 -gravity center -alpha on "%~i"
```

Если перезапись не нужна, то можно создать новые файлы с нужным постфиксом в имени файла:

```
for /r "c:\Folder with Icons" %i in (*.ico) do "c:\program\ImageMagick\convert.exe" "%~i" -resize x32 -gravity center -alpha on "%~dpni_x32.ico"
```